# iteration over a 0-d array-- during run

Tags: python, arrays, plot, iteration

Hi I try to plotting the x, y, z data using this code

```
x = data_sss.iloc[:,0]
y = data_sss.iloc[:,1]
z = data_sss.iloc[:,2]

Lat = np.array('x')
Lon = np.array('y')
SSS = np.array('z')
```

plotting code

```
x_coords = np.arange(min(Lon),max(Lon)+1)
y_coords = np.arange(min(Lat),max(Lat)+1)
Z = SSS(x_coords,y_coords)

fig = plt.imshow(Z,
       extent=[min(Lon),max(Lon),min(Lat),max(Lat)],
       origin="lower")

# Show the positions of the sample points, just to have some reference
fig.axes.set_autoscale_on(False)
plt.scatter(x_list,y_list,50,facecolors='none')
```

However, during run there is a problem which is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20520\368073812.py in <module>
----> 1 x_coords = np.arange(min(Lon),max(Lon)+1)
      2 y_coords = np.arange(min(Lat),max(Lat)+1)
      3 Z = SSS(x_coords,y_coords)
      4 
      5 fig = plt.imshow(Z,

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

I also share the example of my data in the picture. Hope someone can share me on how to counter this problem as I new to python. Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B3Py.png)

Comment: `Lat = np.array('x')` creates an array where the only element is the literal string `'x'`. You probably want `Lat = np.array(x)`. And similar for `Lon` and `SSS`.

Comment: It works, thank you very much.. but there are an error after tried your suggestion which is below

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20520\368073812.py in <module>
      1 x_coords = np.arange(min(Lon),max(Lon)+1)
      2 y_coords = np.arange(min(Lat),max(Lat)+1)
----> 3 Z = SSS(x_coords,y_coords)
      4 
      5 fig = plt.imshow(Z,

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: That looks like it should use square brackets: `Z = SSS[x_coords,y_coords]`. But then then that would need SSS to be a 2D array, whereas you've constructed it from a single dataframe column.

Comment: Thanks it works!!, even though there are another error, but as long as the prior code is solved, i will find solution for the other error. Thank you sooo much